# Efficient way to create parent-child relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

To obtain parent-child relation i use recursion,

```
 public List<MasterDiagnosi> GetAllDiagonsis()
        {
            IEnumerable<MasterDiagnosi> list = this.GetMasterDiagnosi();
            List<MasterDiagnosi> tree = new List<MasterDiagnosi>();
            var Nodes = list.Where(x => x.DiagnosisParentID == 0 && x.Status == 2 && x.DiagnosisLanguageID == 2);
                foreach (var node in Nodes)
                {
                    SetChildren(node, list);
                    tree.Add(node);
                }
            return tree;
        }
        private void SetChildren(MasterDiagnosi model, IEnumerable<MasterDiagnosi> diagonisList)
        {   
            var childs = diagonisList.Where(x => x.DiagnosisParentID == model.DiagnosisID && x.Status == 2 && x.DiagnosisLanguageID == 2);
            if (childs.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in childs)
                {
                    SetChildren(child, diagonisList);
                    model.MasterDiagnosis.Add(child);
                }
            }
        }
```

It work great for 0-500 records, but if i have records more than 5k or 10k then i am ended up with worst case of 4-5 minutes of processing. I am looking for another way around,or any optimization. Currently i save my day using cahce, but i need this to be done as various CRUD operations may be done. Any Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to save the tree data structure **inside the relational database**. In this [presentation of advanced data structures](http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures) you could find some data structures which could be used efficiently to store a tree in a database. Some of them are quite simple.

I have to warn you that these structures **are not always easy to implement**. The gain in performance could be great though.

I have used the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) which I found very efficient. This of course **depends on your specific tree navigation scenarios**. As [Evan Petersen](http://www.evanpetersen.com/item/nested-sets.html) suggests, the nested sets hierarchical model is very sufficient when someone wants to retrieve all the children of one node, but very inefficient for deleting a node because the whole tree has to be reorganized. Therefore, you should make your own decision, by taking your specific tree navigation and update scenarios into account.

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks, that leads me to my solution, i store whole tree graph object in database by serializing it to XML, and vice-verse, that way i don't need to create structure again and again. It give me more flexibility and is less time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable AutoDetectChanges, while you are inserting values into the table, to prevent EntityFramework change tracker firing every time behind on scene. It helped me when I loaded tens thousand records to the database. Look at the example below

```
model.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
// insert data
model.DataBaseContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
model.SubmitChanges();
```